# Delphi generic control possible?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2007, delphi.net

So I have a delphi combobox that looks like this (Rad Studio 2007 .net)...

```
TEnumComboBox<T> = class(TComboBox)
```

the idea is that it can take any enum type and populate itself from there. Struggling to actually get the form that it's used in to compile. I have something in the nfm...

```
object DataTypeBox: TEnumComboBox<DataType>
...
end
```

and something in the pas file, in the published bit...

```
DataTypeBox : TEnumComboBox<DataType>;
```

I get the following error:

> Error: E2217 Published field 'DataTypeBox' not a class or interface
>   type

If I move the declaration of DataTypeBox out of the published bit and into the private bit I get a DCC error code 1.

So, am I wasting my time trying to get a generic control to work in delphi 2007 (Delphi for Microsoft .NET)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are wasting your time. Use a method that doesn't have generics.

Comment: This doesn't work in other .NET designers so I expect it won't be possible here.  You might try defining a concrete type - `TDataTypeEnumComboBox = TEnumComboBox<DataType>` and try sticking that in the form file, ie : `object DataTypeBox: TDataTypeEnumComboBox`.

Comment: You cannot use Generic types in DFMs, they are simply not supported.  Only concrete classes without Generic parameters are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 2007 did not support generics. They were introduced in Delphi 2009.

Comment: Sorry, we are using Delphi .NET 2007 (whether the .NET makes a difference or not, I don't know). Anyway we are using generics in our pas files all over the place, but we've never tried to use generics in a control type.

Comment: Yes, a quick search reveals that the Delphi .NET 2007 compiler supports generics.

Comment: @flobadob That's information that needs to be included in the question. Please edit it to include those important details.

Comment: The *compiler* may support Generics, but the RTL's *DFM streaming system* does not